# Java CompletableFuture chain calls on interface

Tags: java, completable-future

I have some workflow abstraction that relies on an interface `WorkflowStep`:

```
public interface WorkflowStep {

    public void executeStep();
}
```

Now I have got three different classes that implement this interface:

```
GetCoordinatesForWaypoints, DisplayDetails, PlaySounds
```

My aim is to chain them with `CompletableFuture`, currently each overriden `executeStep()` method runs in a runnable, like shown here for example:

```
public class GetCoordinatesForEndpoints implements WorkflowStep {
    @Override
    public void executeStep() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              //download coordinates from open street map
        }).start();

    }
}
```

The other classes methods look similiar. Now I have a central class where the workflow is started. Currently it looks like this:

```
public class DetailsDispatchWorkflow implements DispatchWorkflow {
    private List<WorkflowStep> workflowSteps;

    public DetailsDispatchWorkflow() {
        workflowSteps = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        workflowSteps.add(new GetCoordinatesForEndpoints());
        workflowSteps.add(new DisplayDetails());
        workflowSteps.add(new PlaySounds());
        workflowSteps.forEach(WorkflowStep::executeStep);
    }
}
```

Now I want to replace this with `CompletableFuture`s. The first thing I tried was to do something like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
CompletableFuture<WorkflowStep> workflowStepCompletableFuture = 
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new 
GetCoordinatesForEndpoints().executeStep(), executorService);
```

which gives me an error (I think because the called method returns void). Calling only the constructor works. My next step is to chain those calls with `thenAccept` (because the called actions do not return a value), but that does not work either, when I append

```
.thenAccept(() -> new DisplayDetails().executeStep(), executorService);
```

I get an error that the compiler cannot infer the functional interface type. My quesiton is: How can I achieve the following call chain:

```
CompletableFuture<WorkflowStep> workflowStepCompletableFuture = 
    CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> new GetCoordinatesForEndpoints().executeStep(), executorService)
        .thenAccept(() -> new DisplayDetails().executeStep(), executorService)
        .thenAcceptAsync(() -> new PlaySounds().executeStep(), executorService);
```

when all instantiated objects implement the same interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WorkflowStep` interface is basically equivalent to `Runnable`: no input, no output. In the `CompletableFuture` API, you should thus use the corresponding `runAsync()` and `thenRunAsync()` methods:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> workflowStepCompletableFuture = 
    CompletableFuture
        .runAsync(() -> new GetCoordinatesForEndpoints().executeStep(), executorService)
        .thenRunAsync(() -> new DisplayDetails().executeStep(), executorService)
        .thenRunAsync(() -> new PlaySounds().executeStep(), executorService);
```

This will make all of them run asynchronously, but in sequence (as it seems you are trying to do).

Of course you should also remove the `Thread` creation from your implementation to make this useful.

Comment: Thanks, I think I did not see that method in the javadoc. Just as hint: The type of the CompletableFuture must be Void (since I do not return anything in the method calls). But your approach with passing a runnable lambda works perfect:)

Comment: I had copy/pasted your code and didn't change the type of the future ;)

Comment: thanks for editing, just that no other will complain about incompatible types ;)